# Python3 IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python-3.x

I want to read data from a .CSV .

```
import csv

def read_file(locs):
    with open("/Users/macbookpro/Documents/commit/out.csv") as f:
        reader= csv.reader(f)
        for row in reader:
            locs.append(int(row[3]))
        f.close()

locs=[]
read_file(locs)
```

[image]

this is the .csv file which I read data from.
But it shows error.

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/Users/macbookpro/Documents/testtt.py", line 15, in 
>       read_file(locs)
>     File "/Users/macbookpro/Documents/testtt.py", line 9, in read_file
>       locs.append(int(row[3]))
>   IndexError: list index out of range

But when I pick a smaller number of items in the .csv file,it can successfully run.I don't understand.

Comment: unrealated: `with open()` closes the file when leaving its block. you dont neet to `f.close()`

Comment: please check your whole file - there is bound to be a row with false data in it -containing less then 4columns in one row

Comment: @PatrickArtner Less than 4 colums in a row

Comment: @aloisdg thanks :)

Comment: @PatrickArtner   I checked my data file and I thought it had some problems.I picked the right data and ran it again.Succeeded.Thanks~